# How Grunt watches children folder src, and putting output in same child dest?

Tags: sass, gruntjs, directory, subdirectory

I am new to NodeJs and Grunt, and I want to ask a question that is probably already answered, but I either couldn't understand solution, or couldn't find it.

So, I have www folder with many subfolders with projects. Every project has same folders inside,

```
--css/style.css
--sass/style.scss
--js/script.js + /1.js + /2.js 
--build/script.js
--build/style.css
```

My Gruntfile.js with grunt is at www folder, and my grunt concat, goes something like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
concat: {
  dist: {
    src: ['**/js/1.js', '**/js/2.js', '**/js/script.js'],
    dest: '**/build/script.js'
  },
},
});
```

Now, you can probably see the problem, I get error "Can't create directory C/wamp/www/** ..., and I need to be able to select same folder as where it found js (and later css and other tasks as well).

The most simple solution is needed, and I plan to use concat, watch, uglify, sass (solution for sass is welcome as well).

I am apologizing if this question is repeated, but I can't find an answer.

Comment: I think you will need a concat target for each project folder.

Comment: There must be a way to set for every folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a globbing pattern for your `dest` value, as globbing is for matching patterns. You will need a separate src -> dest mapping for *each* project subfolder. There are a few ways to do this, but I will use the [Files Object Format](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files-object-format). Assuming project subfolders named proj1/ and proj2/, the configuration would look like the following:

```
concat: {
    dist: {
        files: {
            'proj1/build/script.js': 'proj1/js/*.js',
            'proj2/build/script.js': 'proj2/js/*.js'
        }
    }
}
```

If you are going to keep adding project subfolders, it might make sense to build the concat configuration dynamically:

```
var project_dirs = ['proj1', 'proj2'];

var concat_config = {
    dist: {}
};

concat_config.dist.files = project_dirs.reduce(function (memo, dir) {
    var src = dir + '/js/*.js';
    var dest = dir + '/build/script.js';

    memo[dest] = src;

    return memo;
}, {});

grunt.initConfig({
    concat: concat_config
});
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. At least I understand that it can't be done now, and you gave me 1 workaround that I will try.

Answer (score 0):

First

**Concat and uglify your js:**

```
    concat.dev = {
     files: {
       "public/myapp.development.js": [
         "with-bootstrap/public/js/vendor", "with-bootstrap/public/js/**/*.js"
       ]
     }
   };


   //Uglify ===============================
   config.uglify = {
     dist: {
       options: {
         sourceMap: "public/myapp.production.js.map"
       },
       files: {
         "public/myapp.production.js": ["public/myapp.development.js"]
       }
     }
   }
```

**and your sass:**

```
//Sass ===============================
var sass;
config.sass = sass = {};

//distribution
sass.dist = {
  options: {
    style: "compressed",
    noCache: true,
    sourcemap: 'none',
    update: true
  },
  files: {
    "<%= src.distFolder %>": "<%= src.sassMain %>"
  }
};

//development env.
sass.dev = {
  options: {
    style: "expanded",
    lineNumber: true,
  },
  files: {
    "<%= src.devFolder %>": "<%= src.sassMain %>"
  }
};
```

watch your changes in that case I am watching just sass directory:

```
 //Watch ===============================
    config.watch = {
      scripts: {
        files: ["<%= src.libFolder %>", "<%= src.sassFolder %>"],
        tasks: ["dev", "sass:dist"]
          //,tasks: ["dev",'sass:dist']
      }
    }
```

anyway I hope that helps you for start.